# Pass array and string from one script to another script

Tags: shell

Hi have two script one in calling the another.
from one script I m trying to pass two parameters a string and an array.
How can i receive it on another script.
Script 1 :

```
 $admin_script_path/aggregation_checklist_hdfs.sh "${aggregation_hdfs_folder}" "${incrementalArray[@]}"
```

Script 2 :

```
path="$1"
echo "$path"
specificAggregationArray=( "$@" )
```

but these are not working.

Comment: Define "not working"? With the exception of not `shift`ing (or otherwise ignoring) the first argument it looks like that should work.

Comment: Am not able to receive the array inside second script. @Etan

Comment: Add `set -x` to just before the call to the second script and make sure the arguments are being passed correctly. Then check the value of `$#` in the second script and see what `printf %s\\n "$@"` outputs in the second script? As written that call and those lines should set `${aggregation_hdfs_folder}` and the contents of `incrementalArray` as arguments to the second script and collect all of those arguments as `specificAggregationArray` in the second script. How are you checking the array in the second script?

Comment: do you mean 
set -x
$admin_script_path/aggregation_checklist_hdfs.sh "${aggregation_hdfs_folder}" "${incrementalArray[@]}"
May be i am not capturing the argumnets correctly ...